# Nodejs encrypt and decrypt using crypto decrypt badly only firsts characters

Tags: node.js, file, encryption, cryptojs, crypt

I have a js script that crypt and decrypt a file using these two functions

*Encryption*

```
function encryptFile(fileName) {
    const input = fs.createReadStream(fileName);
    const output = fs.createWriteStream(fileName + '.crypt');

    var aes = crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, Buffer.from(key), initVect);

    input
      .pipe(aes)
      .pipe(output)
      .on('finish', function () {
          console.log('FILE ENCRYPTED!');
      }).on('error', error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
}
```

*Decryption*

```
function decryptFile(fileName) {
    const input = fs.createReadStream(fileName);
    const output = fs.createWriteStream(fileName + '.clear');

    const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(algorithm, Buffer.from(key), initVect);

    input
      .pipe(decipher)
      .pipe(output)
      .on('finish', () => {
          console.log('FILE DECRYPTED!');
      })
      .on('error', error => {
          console.log(error);
      });
}
```

Some assumption:

- I use `aes-256-cbc` as algorithm
- key is a 32 char string
- `initVect` is a `crypto.randomBytes(16)`;

Using these two function to crypt and decrypt a file I obtain a bad decryption. No error while execution but when I open the decrypted file the firsts 9 characters is still encrypted. Indeed, if I insert at the begin of my file 9 random charachters, the whole content of my file was decrypted correctly but there are the firsts chars encrypted.
Any solution?

**UPDATE**
I also use these two function passing them the content of the file

*Encryption*

```
function encrypt(text) {
    const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, Buffer.from(key), initVect);
    let encrypted = cipher.update(text, 'utf8', 'base64')
    encrypted += cipher.final('base64');
    return encrypted;
};
```

*Decryption*

```
function decrypt(crypted_text) {
    const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(algorithm, Buffer.from(key), initVect);
    let decrypted = decipher.update(crypted_text, 'base64');
    decrypted += decipher.final();
    return decrypted;
}
```

Using simple string these function work fine, saving the `crypted` (return of encrypt()) in a file, reading it and decrypt it the result `decrypted` (return of decrypt()) has the same problem.

Comment: I can' t reproduce the issue when using *correct* data. However, if you apply a different IV during decryption than during encryption, that would be an explanation. With CBC, a differing IV during decryption leads to a corrupted first block.

Comment: Thanks a lot, to crypt and decrypt I start my script two times and my IV is generated random.